# flatten out indices in order to access elements?

Tags: python, numpy

Let's say I have :

```
one = np.array([ [2,3,np.array([ [1,2],  [7,3]   ])],
                 [4,5,np.array([ [11,12],[14,15] ])]
               ], dtype=object)


two = np.array([ [1,2] ,[7, 3],
                 [11,12] , [14,15] ])
```

I want to be able to compare the values that are in the array of the `one` array, with the values of `two` array.

I am talking about the

```
[1,2] ,[7, 3],
[11,12] , [14,15]
```

So, I want to check if they are the same, one by one.

Probably like:

```
for idx,x in np.ndenumerate(one):
    for idy,y in np.ndenumerate(two):
        print(y)
```

which gives all the elements of `two`.

I can't figure how to access at the same time all elements (but only the last from each row) of `one` and compare them with `two`

The problem is that they don't have the same dimensions.

Comment: if a and b are arrays, you can compare them element-wise with a == b

Comment: hi @george, if I were you, I would go to the python chat before asking here. You know the rules ...

Comment: @BlackBear:The problem is that the dimensions differ

Comment: The fact that these are arrays is almost useless.  `two` is (4,2) shape, so `[1,2]` is `two[0,:]`.  But in `one`, it is `one[0,3][0,:]`.  In an interactive python shell experiment with accessing terms till you figure out a pattern.

Comment: @hpaulj:It's `one[0,2][0,:]` :). The thing is that it confuses me how to access at the same time `one` and `two`.(and let's say that we don't have arrays,we have lists,ok)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works

```
np.r_[tuple(one[:, 2])] == two
```

Output:

```
array([[ True,  True],
       [ True,  True],
       [ True,  True],
       [ True,  True]], dtype=bool)
```

Comment: Hmm..Nice.Can it show me in which indices of `one ` and `two` this occurs?Thanks

Comment: You mean if not all entries are the same? For `two` it's easy, just apply `np.where` to the output array. For `one` I don't even know what exactly you want. You'd have to give an example.

Comment: For `two` you mean `res = np.r_[tuple(one[:, 2])] == two` ,`result = np.where(res == True)`?For `one` I want exactly the same.Just that when we are dealing with `one` we only check the last part (the `one[:,2]` ,the second index in a row )

Comment: Please update your post with an example, like given `[[False, True], [False, False], [False, False], [True, True]]` what exactly do you want as an output for indices; for two: `[0, 3, 3], [1, 0, 1]` for one ??

Comment: Basically,from the (link)[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42067429/access-elements-from-array-of-arrays-call-function-to-execute-array-of-arrays?noredirect=1#comment71349961_42067429] I asked you, I want to do the same thing (`np.r_[] == `) but now I have class instances inside the array.Is there a way to use the `np_r` in this situation?

Comment: I'm afraid `np.r_` only works with arrays. It stacks them on top of each other.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135088/discussion-between-george-and-paul-panzer).

Comment: An alternative to the `r_`, is `np.concatenate(one[:,2], axis=0)`.  Both turn the 2 element object array into a (4,2) array integer array like `two`.

Comment: @hpaulj:Nice alternative,thank you.I am trying to apply it to sth like: [this](http://pastebin.com/3yjeYP6M) but with no success..I don't know if it is applicable to this case.If you have any ideas..Thank you!

Comment: I added an answer exploring this `a`.  Technically it should be in a new SO question.

Answer (score 1):

In a comment link `@George` tried to work with:

```
In [246]: a
Out[246]: array([1, [2, [33, 44, 55, 66]], 11, [22, [77, 88, 99, 100]]], dtype=object)
In [247]: a.shape
Out[247]: (4,)
```

This is a 4 element array.  If we reshape it, we can isolate an inner layer

```
In [257]: a.reshape(2,2)
Out[257]: 
array([[1, [2, [33, 44, 55, 66]]],
       [11, [22, [77, 88, 99, 100]]]], dtype=object)
In [258]: a.reshape(2,2)[:,1]
Out[258]: array([[2, [33, 44, 55, 66]], [22, [77, 88, 99, 100]]], dtype=object)
```

This last case is (2,) - 2 lists.  We can isolate the 2nd item in each list with a comprehension, and create an array from the resulting lists:

```
In [260]: a1=a.reshape(2,2)[:,1]
In [261]: [i[1] for i in a1]
Out[261]: [[33, 44, 55, 66], [77, 88, 99, 100]]
In [263]: np.array([i[1] for i in a1])
Out[263]: 
array([[ 33,  44,  55,  66],
       [ 77,  88,  99, 100]])
```

Nothing fancy here - just paying attention to array shapes, and using list operations where arrays don't work.

Comment: Hmm..you are right!Nice use of reshape here.Thanks for the tip (upvoted)